# Sharepoint - Edit Page does nothing after save

Tags: sharepoint, layout

I can add webparts, write in my content fields like title, subtitle, webpart zones... I can do anything, but when I save, everything disappears; If i edit a page that already has content and just save it, everything disappears the same. The logs show nothing relevant, I have no idea what is wrong.

Edit:

The issue is that whenever I edit a page, imagine to change a title or add a webpart to the rich text html field, through any internet browser, the whole content of the page disappears. My logs show nothing relevant and this is stealing my sleep hours.
Any idea or can I provide you any informating that may help you help me out?
Thank you so much in advance!

Some of the errors i see in logs:

```
Creating object wrapper, expecting major version, but no major version given. URL is /Paginas/testeWP.aspx.
Trying to store a checked out item (/PAGINAS/TESTEWP.ASPX) in the object cache. This may be because the checked out user is accessing the page, or it could be that the SharePoint system account has the item checked out. To improve performance, you should set the portalsuperuseraccount property on the web application. See the documentation for more information.
Failed to get document content data. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Cannot complete this function at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.GetDocumentContentRow(Int32 rowOrd, Object ospFileStmMgr, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq, SPDocumentBindResults& dbres)
```

Edit 2: Here is what i'm doing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gELbR.jpg